# Calculating the inner angle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, expression, iteration

I have some polygons and I want to calculate the inner angle of each polygon. Now, I have the geometry of every line of polygons in the same attribute table as shown in the following image.

[image]

I want to calculate the inner angle using the following equation:

inner_angle= the bearing angle of the previous line - the bearing angle of the following line +180 (in degrees).

How can I write this in the code block in the model builder and do this for each polygon respectively?

***I just need code execute that :***

---

> > > > > > ( Can the iterate feature in model builder do this loop ( **for each polygon**)?)

```
for each polygon

for i = 1: last line in the polygon 

if i < the last line in the polygon 

**angle = the line bearing @ i - the line bearing @ (i+1) +180** 

         if angle >360

            angle= angle -360

         end

        if angle < 0

            angle = angle +360

        end
     else 
     angle =   the line bearing @ i - the line bearing @ first line

         if angle >360

            angle= angle -360

         end

        if angle < 0

            angle = angle +360

        end
     end 

 end
```

---

The desired result as follows:

[image]

Comment: You should try using Python code instead of Modelbuilder. It will still be a bit tricky though. Take a look at the da.UpdateCursor (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that you need a Python script or an iteration.

You can calculate the interior angle of a polygon using this formula: `(n-2) × 180°`, where `n` is the number of sides.

That makes it possible to solve your problem in two steps:

1. Take the [Dissolve-Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) to dissolve the line Feature Class by using the Polygon #ID as the dissolve field and as the statistic field (statistic_type = COUNT) to calculate the number of sides. Now you have the number of sides for each polygon.
2. Use the [Calculate Field Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) to calculate the interior angle of the polygon with the formula shown above.

Both Tools can be easily insert in to your ArcGIS Model.

Comment: This answer is a nice one for the sum of angles. But the formula from the question suggests that the interior angle at each vertex is meant.